# How do I find what $100\%$ is, if $15\%$ is $250,000$?

Tags: percentages

I am doing a budget planning and got problem with this question:

> How do I find what $100\%$ is, if $15\%$ is $250,000$?

Is it

$$\frac{250,000}{15} \times 100?$$

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Yes, if $15\%$ is $250000$, then $1\%$ is $\frac{250000}{15}$, so $100\%$ is what you wrote.  I imagine, from the shape of what you wrote, that this is precisely the reasoning you used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{15}{100}  x = 250.000$

$ x = 250.000 * \frac{100}{15}$

So answer is: yes.

Answer (score 2):

If $15 \%$ of the total $x$, is $250\,000$, then $0.15x = 250 \, 000$. Thus $x = 250 \, 000 / 0.15 = 250 \, 000 \cdot 100/15$. You are correct